# Rails 4.0 config/routes.rb issues wants: http://localhost/api/v1/:controller/:id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Rails 4.0 and I'm trying to get the following routes to work:

```
class Api::V1::MyController
  def get # maps to http GET
  end

  def post # maps to http POST
  end

  ... Same for PATCH PUT DELETE
end
```

and I can't figure out the correct routes.rb.

I've tried several variations:

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', via: [:get, :put, :post, :patch, :delete]
  end
end
```

Results in error: "controller segment is not allowed within a namespace block"

and

```
match '/api/v1/:controller(/:action(/:id))', via: [:get, :put, :post, :patch, :delete]
```

Results in error: "Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant ApiController"

This is what I would like the URL to look like:

```
http://www.localhost.com/api/v1/my_controller/1234
or eventually:
http://www.localhost.com/api/v1/photos/1234
http://www.localhost.com/api/v1/users1234
http://www.localhost.com/api/v1/albums/1234
http://www.localhost.com/api/v1/puppies/1234
```

Comment: what do you want the url to look like?

Comment: @dax Relized a problem with that, I've updated it - ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routes aren't generally done with the controller name as a param - perhaps they can be, but I'm really not sure.  I'd try [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#defining-multiple-resources-at-the-same-time):

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :photos, :puppies, :socks, :bits_of_string
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm trying to follow a guide, that suggests using the HTTP verbs in the manner of http://www.localhost.com/resource/:id and using the verbs to describe the actions necessary, instead of using the action.  The guide is by apigee

Comment: in the manner of ...?  You can use the 'http verbs' but you only need them if you're creating specific actions - `resources :x` creates all the resources with all the actions for a given model

Comment: oh god.  face-palm.  I couldn't see the forest for the trees.

Comment: it happens :) if it helped, please check my answer so the question is taken out of the `unanswered` queue